# assigning value to Read-only computed property

Tags: swift

everyone. I am learning swift and Xcode. and following this https://www.raywenderlich.com/90488/calayer-in-ios-with-swift-10-examples
to learn. i follow every step to do. but i have seen this code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var viewForLayer: UIView!

    var l: CALayer {
        return viewForLayer.layer
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpLayer()
    }

    func setUpLayer() {
        l.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
        l.borderWidth = 100.0
        l.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        l.shadowOpacity = 0.7
        l.shadowRadius = 10.0
    }

}
```

obviously, `l` is read-only computed property.
so how `setUpLayer()` assigns values to `1`?

I used playground to try to assign values to a struct or a class, but it didn't work.

how does this function work?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `l` is a computed property. You can not assign it a value. But it returns you an instance of `CALayer` which you can modify. So you can modify it's `backgroundColor`, `borderWidth` and other properties.

Answer (score 1):

`l` simply returns `viewForLayer.layer`.  The tutorial states:

> The first thing this code does is create a computed property called
>   “l” (that’s a lower case L) to access the viewForLayer‘s layer, which
>   saves some keystrokes as you write the subsequent code.

So what's happening in `setUpLayer` is essentially:

```
    viewForLayer.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    viewForLayer.layer.borderWidth = 100.0
    viewForLayer.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    viewForLayer.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
    viewForLayer.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
```

Which is legal swift.

Comment: but this is read-only. sorry. i didn't make it clear what i want to ask.

Comment: Yes, you can't assign anything else to `l`, like "`l = CALayer()`", because Xcode would throw an error saying "`cannot assign to property: 'l' is a get-only property`".

Comment: thanks! i understand now. i just did a test again. it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand a difference between `reference types` (classes) and `value types` (enums, structs). Read this for more info: [Classes and Structures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html)

Long story short:

`CALayer` is a class, so `l` is referencing to the instance of this class.

If `l` would be a struct, then you wouldn't be able to change any properties for this variable.